# Group Theory commutative diagram

Tags: group-theory

Im in the following situation: 
Let $G$ be a finitely generated group.

$ \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n\times G \rightarrow G$ 
be a split exact sequence.
And let $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ be a short exact sequence.
Moreover, suppose you have surjective homomorphisms 
$\mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow X$, $\mathbb{Z}^n \times G \rightarrow Y$ and
$G \rightarrow Z$ making the obvious diagram commute.

Im trying to compute $Y$, im trying to use diagram chasing to make the second exact sequence split, but i can't conclude.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean simply $\times$ when you write $\otimes$? Otherwise we may be tempted to think that your groups are abelian and $\otimes$ is the tensor product.

Comment: I simply mean $\times$, i will edit it.

Comment: Also, when you say that $Z^n \to Z^n \times G \to G$ "is a split sequence", do you mean that arrows are *the* obvious group homomorphisms, or just two homomorphisms that make the sequence short exact and split?

Comment: Are the obvious homomorphisms

Answer (score 2):

This is simply not true. For example, take $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and consider the commuting diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{lclcl}
\mathbb{Z} & \stackrel{x \to (x, 0)}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} & \stackrel{(x,y) \to y}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{Z} \\
\downarrow \text{id} & & \downarrow f & & \downarrow \pmod 2 \\
\mathbb{Z} & \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{Z} & \stackrel{\pmod 2}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{array}
$$

where $f(x, y) = 2x + y$.

All the vertical homomorphisms are surjective. Both horizontal sequences are short exact sequences. The upper one splits, the lower one doesn't.